# How to traverse nested JsonObjects as a JSON string?

Tags: java, json

I want to extract the value of title using `RestTemplate` and 
`JsonObject` but I can't seem to iterate over it. I am looking to retrieve each object by its key and value. I have tried a few things such as Gson parsing as well and all return product as the only key.

Here's my JSON string:

```
{  
  "product":{  
    "old_labels":{  },
    "available":{  },
    "item":{  
      "tcin":"13860428",
      "bundle_components":{  },
      "dpci":"058-34-0436",
      "upc":"025192110306",
      "product_description":{  
        "title":"Jason Bourne",
        "bullet_description":[  
          "<B>Movie Studio:</B> Universal Studios",
          "<B>Movie Genre:</B> Thriller",
          "<B>Software Format:</B> Blu-ray"
        ]
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my code:

```
JSONObject product = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("product"); 
JSONObject item = (JSONObject) product.get("item");
JSONObject product_description = (JSONObject) 
item.get("product_description");
String title = (String) product_description.get("title");
// returns Jason Bourne
```

Need to do this dynamically:

```
Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
for(Iterator iterator = keys.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     String key = (String) iterator.next();
     System.out.println(jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

But this only returns "product"

Comment: have you tried to debug it?

Comment: yes, it iterates over the json once, returns the first key "product" and exits

Comment: Exits with an error? I suggest looking into JsonPath

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it's what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String filePath = "../json_content.json";
  try {
    JSONParser jsonNParser = new JSONParser();
    String contentJSON = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    JSONObject objectData = (JSONObject) jsonNParser.parse(contentJSON);
    System.out.println(objectData);

    Set<String> keys = objectData.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
      Object keyValueObject = objectData.get(key);
      parseJSONObject(key, keyValueObject);
    }
  } catch (ParseException | IOException ioex) {
    System.out.println(ioex);
  }
}

private static void parseJSONObject(String key, Object keyValue) {
  if (keyValue instanceof JSONObject) {
    JSONObject nextItems = (JSONObject) keyValue;
    Set<String> keySet = nextItems.keySet();
    for (String keyS : keySet) {
      Object objectValue = nextItems.get(keyS);
      parseJSONObject(keyS, objectValue);
    }
  } else if (keyValue instanceof JSONArray) {
    JSONArray objectValueArr = (JSONArray) keyValue;
    String arr = String.join(" | ", objectValueArr);
    System.out.println("Key :: " + key + ", Values :: " + arr);
  } else if (keyValue instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("Key :: " + key + ", Value :: " + keyValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that you used recursion for this. So there is no direct way for this. This definitely works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the json data is very well defined and will always be the way you described then you could use a nested data structure with JsonNode from Jackson like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    String filePath = "../json_data";
    String contentJSON = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
    JsonNode productNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(contentJSON);
    String title = Stream.of(productNode.get("product"))
      .map(item -> item.get("item"))
      .map(pc -> pc.get("product_description"))
      .map(t -> t.get("title"))
      .map(Object::toString)
      .collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(title);
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
    System.out.println(ioex);
  }
}
```

Using this structure you can directly extract the title without using recursion. But the code is predisposed to NullPointerException in case one of the properties does not exist in json to reach the title.